# sleep() and context switching in java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-threads, thread-synchronization

Lets assume a situation like this :

[image]

Lets say `Thread0` access the `lockObject` first and then `Thread0` going to sleep for 1000ms.

```
synchronized(lockObject) {
    Thread0.sleep(1000);
}
```

`Thread1` also waiting for access the `lockObject`.

What happened in these kind of situations?
Is that context switching will pause for 1000ms because of the sleep(1000)?

Comment: What would you expect this to do if the code were to do something else for 1000ms? Why would it do something else for `sleep()`?

Comment: There’s rarely a context switching for just your two threads. The operating system likely will continue switching between threads, but not those two threads.

Comment: Re, "What happened in these kind of situations?" We re-write the application so that it doesn't `sleep()` while holding a lock! We should have designed the program from the beginning so that it never keeps any lock locked for more than maybe a millisecond. Maybe not even that.

Comment: P.S., Can you explain, what does "Contex switching=3ms" mean? What does "context switching will pause" mean? If thread 0 is sleeping while it owns a lock, and at the same time, thread 1 is waiting to acquire the same lock, then neither thread is _runnable_, and therefore, it would be meaningless for either thread to participate in any context switch.

Comment: @SolomonSlow lets say there is not any synchronized() block and wait() method. Then the two threads will access the shared object one by one because of the context switching ryt?ex - thread 1 accessing the shared object until context switching suspend it after 2ms and then thread0 will acessing the shared object for 3ms ryt? Correct me if I wrong

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to learn from an old book. Most computers these days—even most cell phones—have more than one processor. Multithreading no longer just means that the OS executes this thread for so long and then switches to that thread. It's possible, even likely, for two different threads of the same process to run _simultaneously_ on two different processors. IMO, if you are not writing an operating system, then it's unproductive for you to try think about threading at the OS level. Focus instead on learning the _memory model_ of your programming language and its tools.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Thread0.sleep(1000);`, the thread does not release the lock on `lockObject`. So yes context switching will pause for 1000ms.